# How to analyze the data whose different rows have different number of elements using R?

Tags: r

The data format is as following, the first column is the id:

```
1, b, c
2, a, d, e, f
3, u, i, c
4, k, m
5, o
```

However, i can do nothing to analyze this data. Do you have a good idea of how to read the data into R? Further, My question is: How to analyze the data whose different rows have different number of elements using R?

Comment: 1) describe what your data is 2) describe what analysis you want to do 3) read this http://www.sigmafield.org/2011/01/18/three-tips-for-posting-good-questions-to-r-help-and-stack-overflow 4) repost a question with a small data set and code.

Comment: see `fill=TRUE` in `?read.table`.  You probably want to specify `colClasses=rep("character",m)`, too, where `m` is the max. expected number of columns ... (or use `count.fields` to know for sure)

Comment: Are you telling me that you find easier to post a screenshot of data than data itself?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the readLines and strsplit to solve this problem.

```
text <- readLines("./xx.txt",encoding='UTF-8', n = -1L)

txt = unlist(strsplit(text, sep = " "))
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems you are trying to read a file with elements of unequal length.  The structure in R that is `list`.

It is possible to do this by combining `read.table` with `sep="\n"` and then to apply `strsplit` on each row of data.

Here is an example:

```
dat <- "
1 A B
2 C D E
3 F G H I J
4 K L
5 M"
```

The code to read and convert to a list:

```
x <- read.table(textConnection(dat), sep="\n")
apply(x, 1, function(i)strsplit(i, "\\s")[[1]])
```

The results:

```
[[1]]
[1] "1" "A" "B"

[[2]]
[1] "2" "C" "D" "E"

[[3]]
[1] "3" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J"

[[4]]
[1] "4" "K" "L"

[[5]]
[1] "5" "M"
```

You can now use any list manipulation technique to work with your data.